# React Hooks: setState functionality on re-renders

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This is a question regarding a possible performance hit while using hooks.
Quoting `useState` example from react docs:

```
function Counter({initialCount}) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(initialCount);
  return (
    <>
      Count: {count}
      <button onClick={() => setCount(initialCount)}>Reset</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)}>+</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount - 1)}>-</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

> React guarantees that setState function identity is stable and won’t change on re-renders. This is why it’s safe to omit from the useEffect or useCallback dependency list.

I have two queries regarding the usage of `useState` :

- What does `identity is stable and won’t change on re-renders` mean ?
- I can see that for each button an `anonymous` function is passed as event handler. Even if `setState identity is stable` as claimed by React is true, wouldn't the anonymous function be re-created at every re-render ?

Wouldn't it be more efficient if `useCallback` was used to define memoized functions and use them as event handlers ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What does identity is stable and won’t change on re-renders mean ?

The function returned by `useState` will not change across render cycles. That is, the dispatch function returned on the first render cycle can still be called after say, the 10th render cycle to set state. This allows you to setup a hook using the dispatch function at any point without needing to refresh the hook when the function reference changes.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setCount(initialCount);
  }, [ initialCount, setCount ]); // <--- setCount is not needed here
```

> I can see that for each button an anonymous function is passed as event handler. Even if setState identity is stable as claimed by React is true, wouldn't the anonymous function be re-created at every re-render ?

Yes it is true that the arrow functions will be rebuilt on re-render. The alternative is to use `useCallback` to memoize a callback, but at what cost? The cost of invoking `useCallback`, the cost of memoizing that callback, the cost of building references to it and the cost of retrieving that callback on every re-render heavily outweighs the benefits of simply building a function on every re-render.

The `useCallback` function itself is [20 lines long](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/5f06576f51ece88d846d01abd2ddd575827c6127/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.js#L611) with 3 other nested function calls to other internal React APIs. All that to prevent making a single line function on every render? The math simply does not add up in favour of `useCallback`. The only useful scenario is when you want your callbacks to have a "stable identity" either by reference or some other mechanism, so that you can pass the callback as props without causing excessive re-renders.

Comment: But isn't `useCallback` memoization done only once in the best case where there are no deps. The `20 lines` will execute only once. Isn't that still better than a new function creation on every re-render ?

Comment: No, the method has to execute on every re-render to retrieve the memoized callback from the first call to it. It's just that on the first execution the callback is memoized and on the subsequent calls it's retrieved from internal state but it still has to run to do just that.  After all, your component is just a function that runs every time.

Comment: I'd agree that on a large and complex callback function memoizing has performance benefits but not on single line arrow functions.

Comment: Once its `memoized` isn't the retrieve just a lookup which is `O(1)`. Assume the best case where there are no dependencies, hence no re-memoization.

Comment: Did you read the source code I linked? It doesn't just go `if (memoized) return lookupFunction() else return memoizedfunction()`  The method has some set up.

Comment: Yes I did. The main setup happens in `createWorkInProgressHook` method, but in case of re-renders, it'll skip to line `307`. Then in the best case I mentioned above, it'll skip to line `646` to return the callback.

Comment: I'll do some perf tests to verify both approaches. Thank you !!

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying, few function calls, many branch conditions, many temporary variables to allocate. A single line arrow function should be much cheaper. (If it's not that's because the browsers are late in catching up to the es6 standard, not because anything is wrong with the reasoning behind this answer :))

Comment: Cool. While I'm on it, I'll also check how the class variant component fares. Where we can bind an event handler in the constructor. I'm sure there's no universal answer across all scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this component as an illustration for question 1.

```
function Counter({ initialCount }) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(initialCount);

  // after each render we record the value of setCount
  const ref = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = setCount;
  }, [setCount]);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        Did setCount change from since render?{" "}
        {(!Object.is(ref.current, setCount)).toString()}
      </div>
      Count: {count}
      <button onClick={() => setCount(initialCount)}>Reset</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)}>+</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount - 1)}>-</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

1. It means during different component renders useState will be the same (Object.is)
2. Yes anonymous functions will be re-created on every render

> Wouldn't it be more efficient if useCallback was used to define memoized functions and use them as event handlers?

In this particular case, no, because useCallback does not come for free while buttons will be rendered anyway. But when we have a very heavy component to render useCallback will prevent it from unnecessary re-renders

Comment: While I do agree that `useCallback` has an initial cost, wouldn't it be better in the long run ( say more than 10 re-renders). Usually most components do not tend to stop after initial render and are susceptible to re-renders. Hence is there any situation where `useCallback` is not preferred.

Comment: If it was an anonymous function, I believe 10 creations of the same (`dealloc`, `memalloc`, `bind` , etc ) would be more expensive than a single `useCallback`

Answer (score 1):

1. What does identity is stable and won’t change on re-renders mean ?

> your setCount method is stable and won't change on re-renders.

2. I can see that for each button an anonymous function is passed as event handler. Even if setState identity is stable as claimed by React is true, wouldn't the anonymous function be re-created at every re-render ?

> You can but here there is no need to do so as you are not passing it to child component, you should use useCallback if you are passing it to another React component.

Comment: I do not think the second part is correct. I can still give an anonymous function to a react component without any perf differences.

Comment: it can prevent re-renders of child components by using React.memo or React.PureComponent. for example, you have 2 states in your parent component and you are passing only one state in each child. so if any of your state changes will cause re-render of both children because your callback function has different value. but if you pass memoized function by using useCallback it won't re-render.

Comment: Yes, that is true. But if the callback depends on a state, it'll still re-render. Moreover I was more interested in knowing the individual performance of `anonymous` function versus its `useCallback` implementation.